# How to retroactively add a UI Bootstrap Tooltip to some SVG elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

On a project I'm working on, we've created some SVG maps.  We've got a system where we can get information about a particular location on the map from our database.  I'm working on making a UI Bootstrap tooltip appear when the associated polygon is clicked.  However, I've found two ways that don't work.

Way that doesn't work the first, is to simply set up a directive on the overarching element, but set up a system to bind elements in the `link` function of the directive, like so:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').directive('locationMap', [directive]);

    function directive() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                vm: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, elem) {
                var polygons = elem.find('polygon');
                angular.forEach(polygons, function(current) {
                    var currentElement = angular.element(current);
                    var id = currentElement.attr('id');

                    // This function in the VM actually looks up
                    // the given ID, and generates some useful details.
                    // The implementation is unimportant for the question.
                    var formattedText = scope.vm.buildDetails(id);

                    currentElement.attr('tooltip', formattedText);
                    currentElement.attr('tooltip-trigger', 'click');
                    // You have to have this to get this to work with SVG.
                    currentElement.attr('tooltip-append-to-body', true);
                });
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

While this code generates valid markup, clicking on the SVG polygons doesn't actually do anything.  Further research revealed that that's because Angular sets up events and stuff at `compile` time.

So, I next attempted to implement a compile function instead...

```
compile: function(elem, attrs) {
    // Same contents as the link function above.
}
```

...But that doesn't work, because `compile` does not have access to the scope; you have to wait until `link` for access to the scope.

However, if I don't do this at compile-time, I'm dead in the water.

**Question:** In what way can I set up UI Bootstrap tooltips on SVGs that interact on click, but with the detail text coming from the current scope?  I have a feeling I'm overlooking something really simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I had the `link` function, I was most of the way there.  What I needed to do was include the `$compile` service, and use it in my `angular.forEach` loop...

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').directive('locationMap', ['$compile', directive]);

    function directive($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, elem) {
                var polygons = elem.find('polygon');
                angular.forEach(polygons, function(current) {
                    var currentElement = angular.element(current);
                    var id = currentElement.attr('id');

                    currentElement.attr('tooltip', '{{ vm.buildDetails(' + id + ') }}');
                    currentElement.attr('tooltip-trigger', 'click');
                    currentElement.attr('tooltip-append-to-body', true);

                    $compile(currentElement)(scope);
                });                
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

I did that, and my tooltip events are working without a hitch.